# Number of threads within an OMP section

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

My computer has four cores. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10, and compiling using g++ -fopenmp ...

I have two different types of jobs, and both are mutually independent: Work1 and Work2. In particular, Work1 should run on a single processor, but Work2 should be parallelized. I tried using omp_set_num_threads():

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        // Should run on one processor.
        omp_set_num_threads(1);
        Work1();
    }

    #pragma omp section
    {
        // Should run on as many processors as possible.
        omp_set_num_threads(3);
        Work2();
    }
}
```

Say Work2 is something like this:

```
void Work2(...){
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (...) ...

    return;
}
```

When the program is run, only two processors are used. Obviously omp_set_num_threads() is not working as I expected. Is there anything that can be done using OpenMP to remedy this situation?

Thanks to all,

Rodrigo

Comment: instead of `omp_set_num_thtreads` you could use the `num_threads` clause of  `omp section`

Comment: And in addition to the `num_threads` clause, remember to enable nested parallelism with `omp_set_nested(true)` prior to entering the first `parallel` region

Comment: `export OMP_NESTED=TRUE` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get this error when compiling: error: expected end of line before ‘num_threads’
             #pragma omp section num_threads(1)

Comment: I modified the #pragma omp parallel sections with the clause num_threads(4) and, as before, only two cores are used.

Comment: You cannot apply the `num_threads` clause to the individual sections. It can only be applied to the `parallel` construct and to the combined `parallel for` and `parallel sections` constructs. Calling `omp_set_num_threads()` from within the sections is the correct way to set the number of threads used by the nested regions, but you **must** call `omp_set_nested(1)` first or set the `OMP_NESTED` environment variable to `TRUE`.

Comment: Hi Hristo, thanks for answering. Nope, that didn't do the trick, I'm afraid. Do you mean like this? <pre><code>    omp_set_nested(1);
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section 
        {
            omp_set_num_threads(1);
            Work1();
        }

        #pragma omp section 
        {
            omp_set_num_threads(3);
            Work2();
        }
    }
</code></pre>

Comment: I can't seem to add code that looks like code in the comments.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, the OpenMP standard gives no guarantee that the two sections will be executed by different threads (Section 2.7.2 "`sections` Construct"):

> The method of scheduling the structured blocks among the threads in the team is implementation defined.

The only reliable way to have the two work routines execute concurrently is by using explicit flow control based on the thread ID:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
   if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
   {
      omp_set_num_threads(1);
      Work1();
   }
   else
   {
      omp_set_num_threads(3);
      Work2();
   }
}
```

Further, whether the nested parallel region in `Work2()` will use more than one thread, depends on a combination of factors. Among those factors are the values of several internal control variables (ICVs):

- *nest-var* controls whether nested parallelism is enabled; initialised from the value of `OMP_NESTED` and set at runtime by calling `omp_set_nested()`;
- *thread-limit-var* (since OpenMP 3.0) sets the top limit of the total amount of all OpenMP threads in all active parallel regions; initialised from the value of `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` and set at runtime by the application of the `thread_limit` clause;
- *max-active-levels* (since OpenMP 3.0) limits the amount depth of the active parallel regions; initialised from the value of `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS` and set by calling `omp_set_max_active_levels()`.

If *nest-var* is false, then the value of the other ICVs do not matter - nested parallelism is disabled. This is the default value as mandated by the standard, therefore nested parallelism must be enabled explicitly.

If nested parallelism is enabled, it only works at levels up to *max-active-levels* with the outermost parallel region being at level 1, the first nested parallel region being at level 2, etc. The default value of that ICV is the number of levels of nested parallelism supported by the implementation. Parallel regions at deeper levels get disabled, i.e. execute serially with their master threads only.

If nested parallelism is enabled and a particular parallel region is nested at a level no deeper than *max-active-levels*, then whether it will execute in parallel or not is determined by the value of *thread-limit-var*. In your case, any value less than 4 will result in `Work2()` not being able to execute with three threads.

The following test program could be used to examine the interplay between those ICVs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void Work1(void)
{
   printf("Work1 started by tid %d/%d\n",
      omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}

void Work2(void)
{
   printf("Work2 started by tid %d/%d\n",
      omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());

   #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      printf("Work2 nested loop: %d by tid %d/%d\n", i,
         omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
   {
      if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0)
      {
         omp_set_num_threads(1);
         Work1();
      }
      else
      {
         omp_set_num_threads(3);
         Work2();
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Sample outputs:

```
$ ./nested
Work1: started by tid 0/2
Work2: started by tid 1/2
Work2 nested loop: 0 by tid 0/1
Work2 nested loop: 1 by tid 0/1
Work2 nested loop: 2 by tid 0/1
```

The outermost parallel region is active. The nested one in `Work2()` is inactive because nested parallelism is disabled by default.

```
$ OMP_NESTED=TRUE ./nested
Work1: started by tid 0/2
Work2: started by tid 1/2
Work2 nested loop: 0 by tid 0/3
Work2 nested loop: 1 by tid 1/3
Work2 nested loop: 2 by tid 2/3
```

All parallel regions are active and execute in parallel.

```
$ OMP_NESTED=TRUE OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS=1 ./nested
Work1: started by tid 0/2
Work2: started by tid 1/2
Work2 nested loop: 0 by tid 0/1
Work2 nested loop: 1 by tid 0/1
Work2 nested loop: 2 by tid 0/1
```

Despite nested parallelism being enabled, only one level of parallelism could be active, therefore the nested region executes serially. With pre-OpenMP 3.0 compilers, e.g. GCC 4.4, setting `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS` has no effect.

```
$ OMP_NESTED=TRUE OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=3 ./nested
Work1: started by tid 0/2
Work2: started by tid 1/2
Work2 nested loop: 0 by tid 0/2
Work2 nested loop: 2 by tid 1/2
Work2 nested loop: 1 by tid 0/2
```

The nested region is active, but executes with two threads only because of the global thread limit imposed by setting `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT`.

If your have enabled nested parallelism, there is no limit on the number of active levels, and the thread limit is sufficiently high, there should be no reason for your program not to use four CPU cores at the same time...

... unless process and/or thread binding is in effect. Binding controls the affinity of different OpenMP threads to the available CPUs. With most OpenMP runtimes thread binding is disabled by default and the OS scheduler is free to move the threads between the available cores as it deems fit. Nevertheless, the runtimes usually respect the affinity mask that applies to the process as whole. If you use something like `taskset` to e.g. pin/bind the process to two logical CPUs, then no matter how many threads are spawned, they will all run on the two logical CPUs and timeshare. With GCC thread binding is controlled by setting `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` and/or `OMP_PROC_BIND`, and with recent versions that support OpenMP 4.0 - by setting `OMP_PLACES`.

If you are not binding the executable (verify by checking the value of `Cpus_allowed` in `/proc/$PID/status`, where `$PID` is the PID of the running OpenMP process), neither `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY`/`OMP_PROC_BIND` nor `OMP_PLACES` is set, nested parallelism is enabled, no limits on active parallelism levels or thread numbers are imposed, and programs like `top` or `htop` still show that only two logical CPUs are being used, then there is something wrong with your program's logic and not with the OpenMP environment.

Comment: Hristo, your answer is more than I could expect. I really appreciate all the time you devote to explaining all the details. I tried again the modification that you suggested, again to no avail. Only two cores are used. Analising /proc/16882/status, I see that Cpus_allowed: 0f, Cpus_allowed_list: 0-3. I will check the rest. Thank you again.

Comment: I think that the very first code provided by Hristo Iliev is incorrect. According to the OpenMP 2.0 specification, the number of threads cannot be redefined inside a parallel section. Such an attempt will cause run-time errors and program termination of a C++ program. Am I missing something?

Comment: @aligholamee, `omp_set_num_threads()` affects the number of threads for *nested* parallel regions. In that particular case - the parallel region contained in the `Work2` function. The `omp_set_num_threads(1)` call in the first branch of the conditional is not really necessary if `Work1` only contains and calls sequential code.

Answer (score 0):

In GCC sections are implemented as a combination of parallel for and if-then or switch-case statements (or at least it was implemented this way at one point).  Why not do something like this yourself?

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    unsigned ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
    unsigned nthread = omp_get_num_threads();
    if(ithread==0)  work1();
    if(ithread!=0 || nthread==1) {
        //distribute work2 to nthread-1 threads.
        unsigned start = nthread==1 ? 0 : (ithread-1)*N/(nthread-1);
        unsigned end   = nthread==1 ? N :     ithread*N/(nthread-1);
        for(unsigned i=start; i<end; i++) {
            //work2 per iteration
        }
    }
}
```

This method has a few disadvantages though. First it requires that `work1` runs on a particular thread. Second, the thread doing `work1` if it finished before `work2` cannot help finish `work2`.

Here is an alternative method which fixes both of these issues using dynamic scheduling.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{ 
    //while(1) {
    #pragma omp single nowait
    work1();
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        //work2 to per iteration
    }
    //}
}
```

This method has one disadvantage in that the overhead for dynamic scheduling is higher than for static scheduling. However, it no longer requires that `work` run on  particular thread and also if the thread doing `work1` finishes before the threads doing `work2` then that thread can help `work2`. So this method balances the load better.